# Searching in MYSQL using match clause

Tags: mysql, search, sphinx, match, where-clause

OK i want to implement the searching feature using mysql.

Now to do this, i must use the WHERE MATCH Against clause but the problem is that in the below query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH(username) AGAINST('LU' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";
```

It will return rows where username matches 'Lu'
It wont return rows if the username im looking for is 'Lucase' but searching for only two characters from the username.
This might be advanced but im ready for it and if someone could help me out, greatly appreciated.

I think what i want to do is search for rows matching the characters in a string.

I hope you understand what im trying to convey here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the boolean fulltext search. This is a feature, that supports many different operators.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

In your case i would recommend you to search for:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH(username) AGAINST ('LU*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Is there more ways to tweak the search and make it better?
Like facebooks search service, im sure it does more than this.

Comment: also how can i add more values to AGAINST()

Comment: you can use things like '+LU* +Marshall* -Kurt*' and so on. It is pretty flexible, read the documentation (provided above) for more information. If you want more (and speed), use sphinx. It is really really fast and solid. I like it very much.

Comment: thanks a lot, does sphinx work with these same code or some other code?

Comment: sphinx is an additional tool, which you have to install (eventually even compile, depends on your system). It's not as easy as the mysql fulltext search.